# Postgis ST_Azimuth only returning a small range of angles

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have a puzzler with postgis and ST_Azimuth.

I have a table of points (taken from country borders, and run through the QChainage plugin). I want to find the azimuth from a fixed point (15.0,50.0) to each chainage point.

What I want to do is this;

- create a circle centred on NULL island (0,0)
- points form a circle of radius one degree
- angles corresponding to azimuth.

Running this query gives me what I expect; angles are between 0 and 2*PI (with some outliers above this). I translate points so the center is moved to (0,0)

```
select
    st_azimuth(
        st_setsrid(
            st_makepoint(0,0),
            4326
        )
        ,
        ST_translate(geom,ST_x(geom)-15.0,ST_y(geom)-50.0)
    ) as azimuth

from
    qqq3lines
order by azimuth asc
```

To do this, I created a unit vector - a line from (0,0) to (0,1), and rotate it by the azimuth, then take the end point.

```
select
    st_asewkt(
        st_endpoint(
            st_rotate(
                -- unit vector, facing north
                st_makeline(
                    st_setsrid(st_makepoint(0,0),4326),
                    st_setsrid(st_makepoint(0,1),4326)
                ),
                -- rotate by azimuth between central point and this point
                st_azimuth(
                    st_setsrid(
                        st_makepoint(0,0),
                        4326
                    )
                    ,
                    ST_translate(geom,ST_x(geom)-15.0,ST_y(geom)-50.0)
                ) 
            )
        )
    ) as pt

from
    qqq3lines
```

But when I plot this in QGIS, I only seem to get a 'fan', a limited range of angles.
I was expecting a more complete circle.

[image]

The same things happen if I try to do this with custom QGIS python function in the field calculator, using the QGSPoint.azimuth(QGSPoint) method.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you double check the first query's results? I suspect you want ST_Translate(geom, -15.0, -50.0) without ST_X() and ST_Y().